# Beaglebone Black running Debian, does device tree overlay act as an api?

Tags: linux, c++

This maybe more of a Linux specific question but...

I've been reading many tutorials and it seems that you can use JavaScript, Python, and C++ to write code for the Beaglebone Black(BBB).

It looks like the way C++ interfaces with the BBB hardware is via reading/writing text files on the OS while Python has it's own library.

All the C++ examples out there control the GPIO and PWM via reading/writing to text files.

Is this the only way to access the hardware or just how Linux does drivers?

Comment: This question really belongs on Stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how almost everyone does drivers.

When a program wants to communicate with a driver, it needs a communication channel. If every driver introduced a new system call, that would be nigh impossible to maintain, especially as interfaces change, bugs are fixed etc.

Thus, drivers provide a pseudo file that can be accessed with the regular `read`/`write` and `ioctl` calls, which are then directly passed to the driver.

The Python library only provides an abstraction around this interface.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear. I mainly develop on the windows stack so it's definitely a different mindset. If this is just how Linux does it, that's fine. I just wanted to make sure I understood the process. Thanks again.

Comment: [Windows does it too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#win32_device_namespaces).